# The nuts and bolts of Stack Exchange sites

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, technology

Just wondering: what is the front end of SE sites? Is it [LAMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAMP_%28software_bundle%29) like Facebook?

A quick headers check (using `whatismyip`) didn't reveal any details.

The site does hold a huge amount of data and appears to work quickly, so I'm curious about seeing some of the magic involved. :)

Comment: I assume you're looking for the contents of [Which tools and technologies build the Stack Exchange Network?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-build-the-stack-exchange-network)

Comment: You can find a list of the nuts by clicking the large "Users" link at the top of each page.