# yet another question on interesting questions

Tags: discussion, tag-watching

When I call http://stackoverflow.com (and I am logged in simultaneously) I get a collection of questions that appear to be tagged by my favorite tags (to a large proportion).
There's a tab indicating these are interesting questions and indeed the tooltip says

> questions that may be of interest to you based on your history and tag preferences

Below image shows this.

[image: with interesting]

I like this view very much. Unfortunately, when I hit https://stackoverflow.com/questions later on I'm only allowed to select one of *newest, featured, faq, ...*. See below image:

[image: without interesting]

These tabs do also yield interesting questions, but not as interesting as these from the start page. Thus I am forced to hit my favorite button to open the [start page](http://stackoverflow.com) again.

As this feature apparantly is implemented, I wonder why this is "hidden" on the start page and not prominently available from questions...

Comment: `Thus I am forced to hit my favorite button to open the start page again.` And you lose 0.17 seconds in the process. ;P `why such cool feature is "hidden" on the start page and not prominently available from questions` The front page is the worst possible place to _hide_ something, don't you think?

Comment: I wonder why this question is subject to this much downvote activity?

Comment: @moooeeeep downvotes are different on meta, people downvotes here if they are disagree with you . So take it as a sportsmanship. And remember that one downvote is = -2 repo and one upvote is = +5 repo for question.And i have seen that someone has upvoted your question too.

Comment: @Jason true, they also downvote on stuff that look too trivial. For example [my first question here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69427/the-nuts-and-bolts-of-stack-overflow) got a shiny downvote (followed by pity upvote I guess) because those familiar thought it's trivial.

Answer (score 11):

The "interesting" view show collection of questions you are likely to be interested in.

You can always get back to it with one single click on the site logo:

[image: screen shot]

Simple enough, can't see any benefit in yet additional tab in the Questions page.

Answer (score 1):

Your first screen shot appears when you click on the Stack Overflow icon and the second when you click on `questions`.

If I am getting this right, then you are saying that the first screen shot's feature is what you want and not what's in the second screen shot.

But what is the problem with this? Both the features are open, you can select any one by clicking on either the Stack Overflow icon or on the questions tab, both features are not hidden, so there is nothing wrong with it.