# Why did my question here on Meta SO get so heavily downvoted?

Tags: discussion, down-votes, meta

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Any ideas why my question was downvoted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77844/any-ideas-why-my-question-was-downvoted)

I have asked a question on Meta Stack Overflow, which is about whether or not it's proper to change a question on Stack Overflow into a new question by editing it.

I got several answers. The answer I find to be useful disapproves of the change. But what confuses me is the amount of downvotes I got for that question. Why did I receive so many?

[Can I replace an old question by editing it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145773/can-i-replace-an-old-question-by-editing-it)

I checked my spelling, and no person says my question is a duplicate. I really want to know the reason, so that I can avoid these problems in the future. With 9 downvotes I think there must be a serious problem in my question.

Comment: Downvotes are somewhat different on Meta - here upvotes mean people agree/like and downvotes mean that people disagree/dislike - much more than having a direct relation to the quality of the question.

Comment: Read the FAQs, voting on Meta might indicate disagreement depending on how the question is written. The title is like a yes/no question, so people will tend to vote by agree/disagree rather than quality of the post.

Comment: To make it even easier: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences

Comment: @Fluffeh oh I see ,It's because other peolpe don't like

Comment: @Winnie Yep. Simple as that. They most likely mean "No, don't change your question into a new one".

Comment: @UnicornifiedBobby why?is that post mention my question?

Comment: @Bart OMG,but that does an effect on my rep

Comment: @Winnie Meta rep means nothing anyway. I have quite an amount of it and it doesn't mean a thing. It's even more easily gained back really. Don't worry about it.

Comment: When there is a faq explaining the matter we tend to close questions as duplicate of that faq. In your case under "Voting" it says: *On Meta, an upvote indicates "I like this suggestion" or "I agree" and a downvote indicates "I don't like this suggestion" or "I disagree." **Note that downvotes do not necessarily mean that you have asked a question or given an answer that is poorly-formed**. This isn't an official rule, but it has become the de facto accepted community standard*

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd no,his meta question that get downvote is totally different from mine

Comment: @Winnie The answer still universally applies. That is why it's a duplicate in this case here on Meta.

Comment: Of course it's different. But the idea is the same. Look, I also [had a tough start](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69427/the-nuts-and-bolts-of-stack-overflow) (it was -1 for long time) but eventually found my place here just fine. *when in Rome, do as the Romans do* :-)

Comment: @Bart oh ,thanx, it's a very strange way to express disagree.but I feel better now ,thank your word(my English is poor ,I don't know how to describe your word)

Comment: @Winnie We are also strange people ;) Don't worry. Hang around for a while and you'll get to understand how this place (more or less) works.

Comment: @Bart oh I see,thanks.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd OK,I think I should go and familiar with the rules in Rome,Roman

Comment: @Winnie just hang around enough time and you'll learn Metaish really fast.

Comment: A tip: you can delete your questions/answers to regain meta rep if that really bothers you

Comment: @prusswan no it doesn't bother me any more,but thanks your advice